# R studio / R script Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() :

Tags: r, rstudio

Hi I'm trying to make a server in R shiny, I have the following code:

```
    output$map <- renderTmap( {
    cat("renderTmap (initialise map) | ")
    if (input$varID == "Temperture") {
        tm_basemap(c("Esri.OceanBasemap","CartoDB.DarkMatter","OpenStreetMap.Mapnik"),alpha = 0.7) +
            weLayerF(weather,"temp", "feel_like" ,"-RdYlBu", seq(from = 0, to = 45, by = 2))
        
    } else if (input$varID == "humidity") {
        tm_basemap(c("Esri.OceanBasemap","CartoDB.DarkMatter","OpenStreetMap.Mapnik"),alpha = 0.7) +
            weLayer(weather,"humidity", "YlOrRd", seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 2))
        
    } else if (input$varID == "Pressure") {
        tm_basemap(c("Esri.OceanBasemap","CartoDB.DarkMatter","OpenStreetMap.Mapnik"),alpha = 0.7) +
            weLayer(weather,"pressure", "PuBu", seq(from = 980, to = 1030, by = 2))
        
    } else if (input$varID == "Visablity") {
        tm_basemap(c("Esri.OceanBasemap","CartoDB.DarkMatter","OpenStreetMap.Mapnik"),alpha = 0.7) +
            weLayer(weather,"visib", "-Greys", seq(from = 0, to = 10000, by = 500))
        
    } else if (input$varID == "Wind") {
        tm_basemap(c("Esri.OceanBasemap","CartoDB.DarkMatter","OpenStreetMap.Mapnik"),alpha = 0.7) +
            weLayerF(weather,"wind_speed","wind_degree", "Greys", seq(from = 0, to = 30, by = 2))
        
    } else {
        tm_basemap(c("Esri.OceanBasemap","CartoDB.DarkMatter","OpenStreetMap.Mapnik"),alpha = 0.7) +
            weLayerF(weather,"temp", "feel_like" ,"-RdYlBu", seq(from = -10, to = 45, by = 5))
    }
    
})
```

And I'm getting the error:

> Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() :
> Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

Can someone help please?

Comment: Is this all of your code? Where are you calling `renderTmap` from?  Is this code in your `server()` function of your shinyApp? Does this only happen when you use all those `if/else` statements or can you take them out and get the same error?

Comment: Yes this is  in the server function, and there is more code. the server takes in input, output and session and the input is defined when clicking on different buttons on the ui, i havent tried taking out the if/else statments either.